# Does the functional square root of the sine function have an infinite product representation?

Tags: functional-equations, infinite-product, trigonometric-series

We [know](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sine.html) (eq. 23) that the sine can be represented by an infinite product: $$\sin(x) = x \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big{(} 1 - \frac{x^{2}}{n^{2}{\pi}^{2}} \Big{)} .$$ I was wondering whether the function $f$ such that $f(f(x)) = \sin(x)$ has an infinite product representation as well. The function $f$ is called the functional square [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root) of the sine. Perhaps it can also be obtained by means of the Weierstrass Factorization [Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem)?

Comment: You are aware the main point is the analyticity and growth. https://mathoverflow.net/q/45608/84768 assumes $f$ is probably not analytic at $0$

Comment: @reuns yes. Thank you for the link. It'd also be interested in an actual proof that $f$ is not analytic at $0$, $\pi$, $2 \pi$, $\dots$ . If this is the case, we could look for other techniques with which an infinite product can be found. The wikipedia article on the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem mentions a more general theorem for meromorphic functions. Do you know which one it refers to?

Comment: Note that lack of analyticity doesn't mean non-existence of of an infinite product. It only means that one cannot expect one converging uniformly on compacts. Even if  some non-analytic quasi-analytic (e.g Gevrey class) function will not have its Taylor series converging in an open neighbourhood, the series still represents the function and it converges to it in some linear summation method. Potentially one could still have the same sort of result for an infinite product.